# What brand panel is labeled FF130112

Tags: electrical-panel

I need to know what brand panel I have. These are the only markings in the panel:
200 amp outdoor main breaker panel type FF130112

Comment: The best way to get help for that is to [edit] your question and include a picture of an and all labels you can find in the panel (you may need to take the cover off the panel, if you're comfortable doing that), and a picture of all the breakers in the panel. There are many electricians here who will be able to identify the panel, even from partial information, but a picture will be most helpful.

Comment: Picture is very important.  A fast cheap search for electric panel with that number(no good matches) the first hit is federal pacific.  I doubt this is one, but not good if it is.

Comment: Can you post photos of the panel please?

Comment: Yeah, we can typically recommend a panel brand from unique style items, such as the Challenger S-shaped bus bar insulator, or the peculiar old-Murray tail clips that hold the breakers, or the big red Murray main breakers.